# Sublime Text 4: Tools>Build does absolutely nothing

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext4

I've been using Sublime Text for a while and it's worked fine. I have Python 2 and 3 built systems set up for it, which worked great.

At some point recently, for unknown reasons (possibly having to do with the new Sublime Text 4 update, though I think I remember having it work after that) build stopped working entirely.

I'm on a Mac. When I select Build, whether through the Tools menu or Command+B, the tools section of my status bar lights up blue like I've selected something. But ST does absolutely nothing. Nothing saying:

```
Finished: [00.0seconds]
```

The little terminal space for outputs doesn't pop up at all. The bottom left also doesn't say "Building." It doesn't react at all to me selecting build. What makes this particularly strange is I could have sworn it worked perfectly then all of a sudden stopped for no apparent reason, but I could be misremembering? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are there any error messages printed on the console (`Ctrl-\``)? Have you installed any new plugins recently? Changed key bindings or any other system settings? Things don't just happen for no reason.

Comment: Does the status bar display a message like `No Build System`?

Comment: To answer OdatNurd-no it doesn't. To answer MattDMo, there are a couple packages that I have added recently, I'll try deleting those and see if that helps

Answer (score 0):

MattDMo was right, a package did break that functionality in my ST. Specifically, the [ProjectEnvirenment](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ProjectEnvironment) package. Which is unfortunate because I would really like a way to set environmental variables in Sublime Text.

Anyway deleting the package fixed my problem. Thanks  @MattDMo